# What is a Certified form in Adobe LiveCycle Designer context?

Tags: adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

What is a Certified form in Adobe LiveCycle Designer context?
How to make a form Certified?

Answer (score 1):

A certified form is a form that carries the certificate of its vendor/creator (issuer). In essence, it's a "proof" that the form claims to come from whom it comes - "authentic" if you will.

Upon opening a certified form, Adobe Reader will ask the user whether he or she trusts the issuer or not.

In a way you might compare it to an MD5 HASH of a file in a repository, as a means of determining whether someone has tampered with the file.

There are two ways of certifying a form:
1) In Acrobat Professional, choose Advanced->Sign & Certify->Certify with(out) visible signature.
2) In LiveCycle Enterprise Suite, building an application in Workbench whose last step is to apply a certificate using the LiveCycle Digital Signatures ES component.